# AWX default job timeout not applied

Tags: ansible-awx

I'm trying to set my default job timeout on my AWX. when I go to the setting and then jobs settings, I see it's already defined
[settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5Puc.png)

But when I go to a certain job, I see that 'No timeout specified'
[job](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLGOI.png)

Any ideas why is that happening?

Thanks